# How to build orekit from maven?

Tags: maven, build

I am having issues building orekit. I am following this guide below:
https://www.orekit.org/site-orekit-latest/building.html

I have installed jdk and installed java (version 14.0.2) to the path as well as incorporated the necessary users paths (JAVA_HOME, M2_HOME, and MAVEN_HOME). I also installed the latest version of maven version 3.6.3). I tried running "mvn package" and it came up with a build failure:

[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (C:\Users####). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]

I am not very technically proficient using the command prompt. I assume I need something relating to orekit in the same directory. I have a folder labeled orekit which I got from github in the same directory but I still get the error.

Help please.

Comment: Maybe, the file pom.xml is not in the current directory when you run ```mvn package```.

Comment: Thank you! I needed to be inside of the orekit folder where there was a build.xml file before the build would work.